# How can I edit EXIF Data based on the filename?

Tags: photo-editing, metadata, exiftool

I've moved all the photos from my phone to PC (something that I did multiple times along the years from multiple phones) and the date taken is different from the actual date or doesn't exist at all (the only properties that exist is date created and date modified). What I want to do is to change/add "Date taken" based on the name of the photos because the name always contains the proper date in formats like these: "Screenshot_2019-02-22_131421" or "IMG_20190523_113412" or "IMG-20160301-WA0002"

Comment: What have you tried? Does this answer your question: [Software to cross-check EXIF date taken vs date in filename?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/64628/11924)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any software which will set the EXIF Dates based on the file's modification date?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/is-there-any-software-which-will-set-the-exif-dates-based-on-the-files-modifica)

Answer (score 3):

Using [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/), the command you want to use is listed in [ExifTool FAQ #5](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q5)
`exiftool "-alldates<filename" /path/to/files/`

This command creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add [`-r`](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.